# Getting all the leaves from an expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I would like to get a `List` (ideally a set -- discarding repetition -- but assuming there's no direct way to do this I'll just use `Union`) of the leaves from a given expression.

For example, the expression

```
ArcTan[(-1 + 2*x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3]
```

has a `LeafCount` of 18:

- -1 (3)
- 2 (3)
- 3 (2)
- x
- ArcTan
- Plus
- Power (2)
- Rational (2)
- Times (3)

so I would like something like

```
{-1, 2, 3, x, ArcTan, Plus, Power, Rational, Times}
```

Actually, I really just want the functions so

```
{ArcTan, Plus, Power, Rational, Times}
```

would be ideal -- but presumably there's some not-too-difficult way to filter these when I have them.

I've had some luck with

```
H[s_] := If[LeafCount[s] == 1, s, Head[s]]
H /@ Level[expr, 1, Heads -> True]
H /@ Level[expr, 2, Heads -> True]
(* ... *)
```

but I feel like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your own solution does not seem bad:

```
expr = ArcTan[(-1 + 2*x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3];

H[s_] := If[LeafCount[s] == 1, s, Head[s]]

H /@ Level[exp, -1, Heads -> True] // Union
```

```
{-1, 2, 3, ArcTan, Plus, Power, Rational, Times, x}
```

---

Brett Champion's method is more streamlined, but I would change it a little:

```
Union@Cases[expr, h_[___] :> h, {0, -1}]
```

This way you pick up a top level head, such as `ArcTan` in:

```
expr = ArcTan[(-1 + 2*x)/Sqrt[3]];
```

Comment: +1, the level spec, `{0,-1}`, is quite clever: level 0 -> the entire expression, level -1 -> everything without subparts (i.e. the leaves). So, it essentially tells `Cases` to work from top to bottom of the expression tree. Nice!

Answer (score 8):

You could use `Cases` for this:

```
In[176]:= 
Cases[ArcTan[(-1 + 2*x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3], h_[___] :> h, 
  {0,Infinity}] // DeleteDuplicates

Out[176]= {Rational, Power, Times, Plus, ArcTan}
```

Answer (score 6):

For the original question, one can get all leaves via Level with level spec of {-1} and allowing for heads.

```
In[87]:= Level[ArcTan[(-1 + 2*x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3], {-1}, Heads -> True]

Out[87]= {Times, Power, 3, -(1/2), ArcTan, Times, Power, 3, -(1/
    2), Plus, -1, Times, 2, x}
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Where is `Rational`?  The OP requested this.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard I had missed that. In general types that are regarded as "atomic" by Mathematica will not have heads obtained via Level. Depending on what is really wanted that might or might not be a drawback.

Comment: +1 for the `{-1}`. I suspect its more efficient than using `Depth`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I came up with...

```
In[92]:= f[e_] := DeleteDuplicates[Prepend[Head[#] & /@ Level[e, Depth[e]], Head[e]]]

In[93]:= f[ArcTan[(-1 + 2*x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3]]

Out[93]=  {Times, Integer, Rational, Power, Symbol, Plus, ArcTan}
```

You can then easily remove `Integer` and `Symbol`.

---

*Edit:*

Now let's wrap the expression in a list to make sure we're getting the uppermost head. (The original expression had `Times` as its head but it was also twice inside.

```
In[139]:= a = {ArcTan[(-1 + 2*x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3]}
In[140]:= TreeForm[a, AspectRatio -> .7]
```

[image: TreeForm]

```
In[142]:= f[a]
Out[142]= {List, Integer, Rational, Power, Symbol, Times, Plus, ArcTan}
```